# Isothermal solar wind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you integrate the equation for the Parker solar wind? I'm stuck on simplifying the integral and can only seem to get

$$
\frac{v^2}{2}-\ln(v)=\ln(r)+\frac{r}{r_c}
$$

I'm close to quitting at this stage

Comment: That is the integral result

Comment: What is the original equation?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the result, rewrite the equation as
$$\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac 12\ln(v^2)=\ln(r)+\frac{r}{r_c}$$ Now, let $x=v^2$ and $k=2\left( \ln(r)+\frac{r}{r_c}\right)$ to make
$$x-\log(x)=k \implies x=-W\left(-e^{- k}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function.